# Add product to downloadable/customer/products/

Tags: addtocart, downloadable, ajaxaddtocart

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$FormKey = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey'); 
?>

<form action="http:localhost:3000/checkout/cart/add/product/1223/" class="add-downloadable-form" method="post">
            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey();?>">
            <input name="uenc" type="hidden" value="">
                    <button type="submit" class="button product-addcart-blue">
                                <span>Add to my Downloadable</span>
                            </button>
        </form>
```

and I want to add the product to My Customer Account in My Downloadable Products - possible? if yes, can you explain this?

Comment: can you please explain this in details what actually you are looking.

Comment: I have a fixed product id, there is a template that I connect to the page where there is a button to add to the library (it is available only to those who are registered), when I click on the button, I need to add a product to the My Downloadable Products section so that the user can download product

Comment: Is this product is downlodable? and you want to provide directly that product as download without placing order?

Comment: yes, this product type is downlodable and yes, without placing order if possible

Comment: Then how show to customer to download the things?

Comment: he logs into his account in the section My Downloadable Products and can see this, and if need he can download

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128403/discussion-between-lerry-and-dhiren-vasoya).